# How to make images in a CSS Grid lay next to each other and jump to another row when lacking space

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to position images the way shown in the picture using CSS Grid and I can't find a right solution.

Right now I'm simply changing the grid flow to column, but the grid elements don't jump to another row when they meet the end of the container - they resize it and stay in the same, first row.

I tried to use `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(16rem, 1fr))` - it solves this *jump to another line* issue, but it gives all the elements a fixed width whereas some images are not that wide. It creates empty holes between images which I'd like to avoid.

[image: properly positioned images picture]

Any ideas on how to accomplish it?

[wrong solution 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh89B.png)

Code from the image above:

```
container {
            display: grid;
            grid-gap: 1rem;
            grid-auto-flow: column;
        }
photo { // all container's elements have this class
            height: 10rem;
            width: auto;
        }
```

[wrong solution 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr3xK.png)

Code from the image above:

```
container {
            display: grid;
            grid-gap: 1rem;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(16rem, 1fr));
        }

photo {
         height: 10rem;
         max-width: 100%;
      }
```

Comment: Coluld you post the code you did so far? Without any code it is hard to spot where the problem may be.

Comment: Added images and corresponding code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see, this is tusk for `flex`, not for `grid`. Using `grid` means columns with same width on each row. No need here at all.

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.conteiner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.photo {
  height: 10rem;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
}
.photo img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteiner">
  <div class="photo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x200"></div>
  <div class="photo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"></div>
  <div class="photo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"></div>
  <div class="photo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200"></div>
  <div class="photo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x200"></div>
  <div class="photo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"></div>
  <div class="photo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"></div>
</div>
```

Although I'm using [Justified gallery](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/) jQuery plugin, if I wand all images in each row to fill all the width.

Comment: Oh yes, it's so simple! I totally forgot about using flex in this type of situation, thank you!
 I'll also check that plugin.