# How to Lay Images Side by Side into 2 Columns, 'overflowing' into the next row

Tags: html, css

I apologize in advance, if there is already a similar question asked and answered. However, I could only find threads in which the number of images are known and fixed.

I need to lay images side by side, but overflowing into the next row. For example, if there are 3 images, then first two images would be side by side on row 1, and then 3rd image would take its place on the next line, with an empty space underneath the 2nd image. If there are 5 images, then it goes two on first row, two on second row, and the last image in the first column by itself.

I am using handlebars-v4.5.3.js. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row2" class="keep-together">
{{#each imageResults}}
   <div class="column imageContainer">
     <div class="defaultImage">{{{imageResult}}}</div>
   </div>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

Here is the corresponding CSS:

```
.row2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
  flex: 45%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.defaultImage img {
width: 100%;
}

.imageContainer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
}

.keep-together {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

This is how I am able to get it to look so far. I am successful in getting the two images to lay side by side, however, if the number of images happen to be odd, (i.e. the last image is by itself on its row), then the last image will take up the entirety of the div.

[image: Current View]

Comment: flexbox with `flex-wrap: wrap`

Comment: Thank you so much @melancia ! I was able to use those suggestions and it resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For closure, I was able to resolve my problem with the help from this solution, [How to make images in a CSS Grid lay next to each other and jump to another row when lacking space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62644200/how-to-make-images-in-a-css-grid-lay-next-to-each-other-and-jump-to-another-row):

I changed my HTML to:

```
<div class="imageContainer">
  {{#each imageResults}}
    <div class="defaultImage">{{{imageResult}}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

And my CSS to:

```
.defaultImage {
  height: 20rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.defaultImage img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.imageContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20rem, 1fr));
}
```

This allowed me to put images in a grid and overflowed the images correctly.